# Python: flipping images horizontally and reordering targets

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am following this [tutorial](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/) about **data augmentation** for this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection/data)
about **facial key-points detection** (identified by (x,y) target coordinates).

I want to **flip images** horizontally, so also some targets need to be swapped in this way:

```
left_eye_center_x --------->> right_eye_center_x
left_eye_center_y --------->> right_eye_center_y
left_eye_inner_corner_x --------->> right_eye_inner_corner_x
left_eye_inner_corner_y --------->> right_eye_inner_corner_y
...
```

The image flipping and the coordinates reordering seem **fine when printing**, but **not when plotting**.

**code:**

```
# target indices to swap
flip_indices = [(0, 2), (1, 3),(4, 8), (5, 9), (6, 10), (7, 11), (12, 16),
                (13, 17), (14, 18), (15, 19),(22, 24), (23, 25)]

# permutation that represents the target coordinates reordering
permutation = [2, 3, 0, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5,
              6, 7 ,16, 17, 18, 19, 12, 13, 14, 15,
              20, 21, 24, 25, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29]

X_train_flipped = np.flip(X_train, axis=2) # flips images horizontally
Y_train_flipped = np.copy(Y_train)[:,permutation] # flips targets according to permutation

print (Y_train[1,permutation] == Y_train_flipped[1]) # permutation seems successful    

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
# original image, original targets
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
plot_sample(X_train[1], Y_train[1], ax)

# flipped image, original targets
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2, xticks=[], yticks=[])
plot_sample(X_train_flipped[1], Y_train[1], ax)

# flipped image, flipped targets
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3, xticks=[], yticks=[])
plot_sample(X_train_flipped[1], Y_train_flipped[1], ax)
```

**Output:**

```
[ True  True  ... True  True]
```

The third picture should have the targets correctly positioned.
[image]

The function `plot_sample()` is defined in the tutorial like this:

```
def plot_sample(x, y, axis):
    img = x.reshape(96, 96) 
    axis.imshow(img, cmap='gray') 

    axis.scatter(y[0::2] * 48 + 48, y[1::2] * 48 + 48, marker='x', s=10)
```

Comment: not really familiar with the dataset, what should `flip_indices` represent? looking at the images... I'd create a binary mask for the target indices, flip that and get the indices back with `np.where`

Comment: It means that array[0] takes the value of array[2] and viceversa. And so on for the other positions

Comment: ok, but you don't seem to be using it here, am I wrong? anyway, what I was suggesting is to turn your ground truth into an image so you can apply the very same transformation you apply to the input. In this specific case you could just call `np.flip` on both `X` and `Y` instead of manually messing with index permutations.